# Grid is not flexible enough to sort the posts

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a curious grid problem and I just can’t work out the solution for it!
I have designed a site with grid to accommodate artwork of my client and I have build it with WordPress and CSS grid. This grid is working fine and accommodates the work as I want, but the problem comes when I’m using the post sorting tabs in the top (Illustration, Paintings or Sketches). When you click one of those tabs, the artwork gets hidden (by applying display: none;), but not removed from the grid which results in empty spaces in the grid.

This is happening because I'm placing each element in the grid with :nth-child for example:

```
.grid__item:nth-child(2) {
    grid-row: 1 / span 5;
    grid-column: 8 / 10 span;
}
```

My grid css is following:

```
.grid--category {
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
        grid-column-start: auto;
        grid-gap: 7px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(19, 6vw);
    }

    @media (min-width: 1530px) {
        grid-template-rows: repeat(19, minmax(68px,min-content));
    }

    .grid__item {
        @media (min-width: 480px) {
            grid-column-start: auto;
            grid-row-start: auto;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;

            // 1st row
            &:nth-child(1),
            &:nth-child(2),
            &:nth-child(3) {
                grid-row: 1 / span 5;
            }
            // 2nd row
            &:nth-child(4),
            &:nth-child(5),
            &:nth-child(6) {
                grid-row: 6 / span 5;
            }
            // 3rd row
            &:nth-child(7),
            &:nth-child(8),
            &:nth-child(9),
            &:nth-child(10) {
                grid-row: 11 / span 4;
            }
            // 4th row
            &:nth-child(11),
            &:nth-child(12),
            &:nth-child(13) {
                grid-row: 15 / span 5;
            }

            &:nth-child(1) {
                grid-column: 8 / 10 span;
            }
            &:nth-child(2) {
                grid-column: 1 / span 7;
            }
            &:nth-child(3) {
                grid-column: 18 / span 7;
            }
            &:nth-child(4) {
                grid-column: 1 / span 8;
            }
            &:nth-child(5) {
                grid-column: 9 / span 8;
            }
            &:nth-child(6) {
                grid-column: 17 / span 8;
            }
            &:nth-child(7) {
                grid-column: 1 / span 6;
            }
            &:nth-child(8) {
                grid-column: 7 / span 6;
            }
            &:nth-child(9) {
                grid-column: 13 / span 6;
            }
            &:nth-child(10) {
                grid-column: 19 / span 6;
            }
            &:nth-child(11) {
                grid-column: 1 / span 8;
            }
            &:nth-child(12) {
                grid-column: 9 / span 8;
            }
            &:nth-child(13) {
                grid-column: 17 / span 8;
            }
            &:nth-child(1n) {
                .card__title {
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .grid__item-header {
        @media (min-width: 480px) {
            border-width: 0 7px 7px 7px;
            margin-left: -7px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #fff;
            height: 109%;
            z-index: 10;
            width: 107%;
        }

        @media (min-width: 770px) {
            width: 104%;
        }

        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
            width: 103%;
        }
    }
}
```

Design is:

[image: site-design]

My question is what technique would be the best for building this exact grid design? It really needs to be flexible for sorting tabs to work.
Is it possible to build this design with CSS grid but keep it enough flexible? or any other technique you would recommend? Any ideas or advice how to tackle this grid would be very appreciated!!

You can see the current implementation on staging here: http://www.wp-staging.pixelsandbeyond.io/drawings/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of days pulling out my hair, I have found a similar layout in Jen Simmons labs: https://labs.jensimmons.com/2016/examples/image-gallery-grid-1.html

This seems to be the closest to what I need, so I'm just going to stick with it and closing this question. Thanks!